# Allowing users to input raw SQL in update statement safely

Tags: sql-injection, postgresql

I'm building an application and I have some very, very advanced users who can come up with endless filters they want. They know SQL so in the end gave them some of the filters and said in the bottom of the screen you can have your custom filter, where you can write your own filter in SQL. And they where pleased. So my question is what checks do I have to perform to be sure that they can't ruin the database. There is no confidencial information and no passwords since these are performed with single sign on.

The surrounding query where they can inject SQL looks like this:

```
UPDATE table
SET col_a = val_b
WHERE {potentially some other filters}
AND {injected SQL};
```

I currently don't allow `;`, but what else should don't allow? I'm using a postgres database and python using psycopg2.

Comment: From what language/framework/library are queries being made? Make sure it doesn't allow multiple queries in a single call.

Comment: You have to whitelist, not blacklist. The SQL language can change, and even if you think of every possible bad character or operator now, there *will* be something new in the future. Think of a list of the operators that you want to allow, and block *everything* else.

Comment: @multithr3at3d if I don't allow `;` how is it then posible to put multiple queries inside the statement?

Comment: @PeterMølgaardPallesen another query without `;` can be added by using subqueries.

Comment: @PeterMølgaardPallesen I don't know, there's probably some other way. That's why blacklisting is no good

Comment: @BenjaminH As far as I'm concerned subqueries can't perform manipulations. Or is there something I don't understand?

Comment: @PeterMølgaardPallesen you are probably right, but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: The language/library/framework/database you are using make all the difference here. Would you mind editing your question to add those?

Comment: If you allow this to happen, there will most likely be a way to exploit it. There has to be a better way than to allow users to directly interact with the data in the database through a GUI (without authentication?).

Answer (score 7):

### Restricted user accounts

Sanitizing such a query securely may be very, very hard and you should expect that you might have failed in some way which allows the users to execute arbitrary sql.

A possible mitigation for this would be severely restricted user accounts - you need to ensure that the connection under which these queries are executed is run under a user account which can access *only* the specific tables which you expect to be used, and can modify *only* the specific table which is expected to be updated.  It may be that this needs to be a different database user account (and a different connection) than what the rest of the system runs on.

Answer (score 0):

The heavy-lift answer is a creating a domain-specific language with ANTLR or its ilk and transforming that to known-good parameterized SQL.